# Django юнит тестирование активации пользователя

Tags: django, юнит-тесты

Я пытаюсь сделать *юнит-тест* для процеса активации пользователя (тест для регистрации сделан).

Функция которую хочу протестировать:

```
def signup_complete(self, data):
    try:
        code = VerificationCode.objects.select_related('user').get(code=data["code"],
                                                                   code_type="registration",
                                                                   expiration_date__gt=timezone.now())
    except VerificationCode.DoesNotExist:
        raise NotFound(_(u"Неверный код восстановленыя"), 1001)
    user = code.user
    user.is_active = True
    user.save()
    code.delete()
```

мой тест:

```
def test_signup_complete(self):
    user = SiteUser.objects.get(email="test@gmail.com")
    code = VerificationCode.objects.create(user=user, code_type="registration", code=user.code)
    #data = serializers.serialize('json', [code])
    data = serializers.serialize('json', [code], fields=('user', 'code'))
    UserService(user).signup_complete(data)

    self.assertEqual(user.is_active, True)
```

у меня не получается передать параметер для функции `signup_complete`.

Comment: Юнит-тесты - это тесты для отдельных модулей и классов, не для всего приложения целиком

Comment: Почему не получается? Вы получаете ошибку, в таком случае добавьте в вопрос сообщение об ошибке. Меня смущает строка `serializers.serialize('json', [code], fields=('user', 'code'))` хотя в самой функции (судя по всему) используется `dict`

Comment: да вы правы я переделал на диктионари и тепер кидает NotFound(_(u"Неверный код восстановленыя"), 1001)